# How do the right-handed fermions acquire mass?

Tags: mass, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

I am constructing a presentation on how elementary particles acquire mass via interaction with Higgs field. I asked this question previously in a different form and received the usual clap trap, so I researched it personally.  I have most everything else ready but the following.

What I need to know specifically right now, is how do the right handed elementary fermions acquire mass? or don't they? I am familiar with the process for the left handed fermions re absorption and emission of the weak hypercharge.

No maths please plain English if anyone is willing to respond.  Pls don't send me to text books or other websites.

Comment: Perhaps this is related to ESB ( electroweak symmetry breaking), and these masses are generated by the Higgs vacuum expectation value and goes to new pathways for  physics beyond the Standard Model.see for discussion:http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/06/19/helicity-chirality-mass-and-the-higgs/

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to fairly explain the origin of masses – and most other things – without "any mathematics" at all.

Charged fermions get masses through their cubic "Yukawa" interactions with the Higgs
$$ L_{Yuk} = y\cdot h \psi_L \psi_R $$
When the Higgs field is $h=v$ in the vacuum, the simple part of this cubic term generates the quadratic term
$$ m \cdot \psi_L \psi_R $$
which is the mass term for the fermion, $m=yh$. Note that the mass term is something that depends both on the left-handed field and the right-handed field. Charged particles' masses cannot be chosen separately for the left-handed and right-handed parts. The Dirac mass *is* something that allows the left-handed chiral fermion to turn into the right-handed one and vice versa. (The angular momentum is preserved in these processes but the helicity is not.)

The situation is different for neutrinos, the neutral fermions we know. In that case, there may still be masses of the Dirac type I just mentioned. But there may also be Majorana mass terms proportional to $\psi_L \psi_L$ that violate the lepton number by $\Delta L = \pm 2$. For the visible left-handed neutrinos, these terms cannot appear at the tree level. But they may be generated as an effective interaction from some high-scale physics. The high-scale physics may also contain Majorana mass terms with a very heavy mass for the right-handed neutrinos, $M\psi_R \psi_R$. The coefficient $M$ here may be high, e.g. at the GUT scale. This mass term doesn't contradict any known conservation laws because $\psi_R$ is a Standard Model singlet (carries no conserved charges or representations).

Comment: Hi @Lubos. I know this is very late but just so I understand this correctly-the $\nu_L\nu_L$ mass term in the effective SM action could come from integrating out as yet unknown heavy modes in a UV theory. Moreover, the $\nu_R\nu_R$ interactions that we don't see at low energies- should actually exist in the UV since nothing forbids it. If I have understood you correctly so far, then is it correct to say that understanding the origin of the $\nu_L\nu_L$ term reduces to tracing the interactions in the UV theory that give rise to it? Also, what are the signatures of UV $\nu_R\nu_R$ term in SM ?

Comment: Hi! I think all your statements with periods are right. I am just not sure whether we understand that we have no evidence of EXISTENCE of $\nu_R$, not only the interactions. Otherwise your first question asks whether tracing carefully UV terms is enough to understand low-energy effective physics. Of course, it's the point of reductionism, as clarified by the renormalization group, that all the low-energy physics may be derived from the UV laws.

Comment: To see signatures of the Majorana terms for right-handed neutrinos, you must first observe right-handed neutrinos. Then you try to reconstruct the whole mass matrix. Ideally, you may create the heavy particles themselves and detect them. Unlikely. But there are differences for Majorana vs Dirac dominant masses, like neutrino-less beta decay that proves that neutrinos may violate L by two, so the mass isn't purely Dirac, and other things.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!(for this, and the many other wonderful answers you have on this site- they're very enjoyable and insightful).